JavaScript rounding works icncorrectly
That's crazy! I tried vast majority implementations of rounding, but one case still fails.
Math.round((130.325) * 100) / 100 // 130.32 incorrect (should be 130.33)
BUT
Math.round((30.325) * 100) / 100 // 30.33 correct
and any other value different from 130.325 has correct rounding. As far as I realize, left part before the dot can't affect on rounding, isn't it?
Why those 130.325 and 30.325 numbers has different result of rounding after the dot ?
Please help me to found the solution.
UPD
My solution:
static round(value: number) {
  const rounded = Math.round((value + Number.EPSILON) * 1000);
  return Math.round(rounded / 10) / 100;
}


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round
print both numbers you are passing to Math.round using console.log. You will realise that first number is slightly less than 0.5 due to precision errors in floating point numbers. Hence got rounded down. Second one decimal part is exactly 0.5, so rounded up

Please look at my example, I don't pass any variable to Math.round, I pass raw numbers. Did you try to execute examples in your console?

console.log((30.325) * 100); // 3032.5
console.log((130.325) * 100); //13032.499999999998

I could never think about that   ¯_(ツ)_/¯ .
